# Embedded Mono: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) when calling mono_jit_cleanup()

Tags: macos, mono, exc-bad-access, mono-embedding

I'm embedding Mono runtime into existing Cocoa application. I've built the latest runtime from GitHub (master branch) and exiting application after running some managed code gives me this during the mono_jit_cleanup():

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/108566029/BAD_ACCESS.png

It's only reproduced when I try to send HTTP request via HttpWebRequest. Specifically if I call GetRequestStream(). The code works fine and all the managed objects are disposed correctly. The mono_jit_cleanup() is called only once. The problem occurs only during shutting down the runtime.

This is also reproduced on the latest Mono 2.10.x branch. But I get SIGSEGV then.

This can occur in different places, so it seems like a threading issue.

So, how should I shutdown the runtime correctly. Is mono_jit_cleanup() call sufficient to correctly dispose of the runtime? And can I exit the application without disposing runtime (no mono_jit_cleanup() call)?

P.S.
I'm using 32-bit build of Mono v2.0 (3.5 actually) runtime on OSX 10.8.3. I link against libmono-2.0.1.dylib, so it should be Boehm GC. The same problem is also reproduced with SGen GC.

P.P.S
Here goes another error https://dl.dropbox.com/u/108566029/SIGABRT.png

Answer (score 0):

The standard mono executable calls mono_jit_cleanup() just fine, so we'd need to know more about what exact code you're calling, in which thread etc.

In any case, you can just exit the application without calling that function.